# Minha Credencial Google Maps API parou de funcionar

Tags: android, google-maps, google

Tenho uma aplicação Android e não está mais carregando os marcadores no mapa, aplicação que está ativa na Google Play Store, não foi feito update no apk, não foi alterado chave no Google Cloud Console, simplesmente parou. Já verifiquei no Logcat do Android Studio e está tudo ok. Nesse último mês a Google mudou seu nome de Google Console Maps para Google Cloud Console e alterou políticas internas, como por exemplo a obrigação de cadastrar forma de cobrança dos seus serviços, apesar de darem crédito e eu já efetuar essa operação ainda minha aplicação é afetada. Alguém teve problema com autenticação da API Google Maps nessa mudança deles? Se alguém tiver uma ideia do que pode ser, agradeço.
[image: Maps não carrega]

Comment: Já tentou atualizar a chave da API?

Comment: Atualizando a chave vou ter que copilar nova versão do apk, estou pensando até na possibilidade de ser limite de marcadores no mapa, tenho mais de 140 marcadores recuperados do Firebase. Será que tem limite de markers no mapa?